# Swift - Alamofire returns "Invalid request format." when I try to upload file to pinata

Tags: swift, alamofire, ipfs

print(element) print following

error = "Invalid request format."

Although the response.result is success.

I don't know what to do... appreciate any help.

```
let request = AF.request("https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
          method: .post,
          parameters: data,
          encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
          headers: [
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=nadeshiko_data_boundary",
            "pinata_api_key": "myAPIKey",
            "pinata_secret_api_key": "mySecretApiKey"
        ])
        request.responseString { response in
            print("responseString responseee", response)
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let element):
                print(element)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("failure", error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: - success : "{\"error\":{\"reason\":\"INVALID_API_KEYS\",\"details\":\"Invalid API key provided\"}}"   You have to enter valid API key for get the proper response from API. Insert valid key of pinata_api_key and pinata_secret_api_key first.

Comment: Thank you for answering! but I do enter valid api key and private key in my actually code.

Comment: can you show me the response so I can identify the issue?  of response.result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked to pinata support.

Turns out I was trying to upload JSON file where I have to upload a File.